# Better methods to convert this numeric string with commas to float in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, locale, setlocale

I am using python v3. I have this string `1,027.86`. I want to convert it to float `1027.86`.

I found a solution while googling.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "nl")
price = '1,027.86'
price = locale.atof(price)*1000
```

I searched the documentation on what `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "nl")` means but could not find an answer. 
http://dc.dyu.edu.tw/python/350/library/locale.html

Is there a better argument to put inside `setlocal()` that will return the result directly without the need of multiplying by 1000 later?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about `setlocal()` arguments ro do you just want to convert the string to a float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying `nl` for `setlocale()` is telling it to default to the format for the Netherlands. If you use something like `uk` it should convert correctly as the numeric format is of the form`xxx,xxx,xxx.xxx`.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "uk")
price = '1,027.86'
print(locale.atof(price))
```

This would display:

```
1027.86
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple string replacement to turn it into a float that can be properly parsed `price = float('1,027.86'.replace(',',''))`.